# Will api gateway forward headers downstream

Tags: api-gateway, mi

What are the headers that will be forwarded and what will be modified and dropped

Comment: Hey. your question is totally unclear, please put some effort to make it answerable by stack users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some exceptions, by default, API Gateway forwards all headers on incoming requests to the downstream services. 
The most notable exceptions, ignoring whitelisting and other specific features:
- Authorization header if the request is authenticated with Security Token Service - Accept header and Content-Type header may be manipulated based on the route configuration and version: https://confluence.inside-box.net/display/ETO/On-boarding+new+APIs#On-boardingnewAPIs-HeaderManipulation